# Firebase database set value doesn't change the value

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

*first I'm beginner*

I'm trying to upload some data to firebase and its collection of objects,
so I convert it to JSON format and upload it as String just like saving arrays in SharedPreference
(i mean the idea to convert array to string)

here are the rules:

```
{
  "rules" :  {
    ".read" : true,
    ".write" :  true
    }
}
```

here is the Data Class:

```
data class Content(
        val books: List<Book>,
        val poems: List<Poem>,
        val proses:List<Prose>
```

I create a class to manage all processes with firebase
here:

```
class SdDataManager {

    // get database
    private var database: FirebaseDatabase = Firebase.database
    private var content: Content?
    
    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "SdDataManagerTag"
    }

    init {
        content = null
        
        // read data
        val contentReference = database.getReference("content")
        contentReference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {

            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                val gson = Gson()
                val json: Map<String, Any>? = snapshot.getValue<Map<String, Any>>()


                content = gson.fromJson(json.toString(), Content::class.java)
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Failed to read data error: " + error.toException())
            }

        })


    }
    
    // this function is only for testing

    fun test() {
        
        // creating content object
        
        // create test bitmap
        val conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(512, 512, conf)
        
        val chapters = listOf(Section("SEC_TITLE", "SEC_BODY"))
        val book = Book("BOOK_TITLE", chapters, bitmap)
        val books = listOf(book)
        val poem = Poem("POEM_TITLE", "POEM_BODY", bitmap)
        val poems = listOf(poem)
        val prose = Prose("PROSE_TITLE", "PROSE_BODY", bitmap)
        val proseList = listOf(prose)

        
        val testContent = Content(books, poems, proseList)
        updateContent(testContent)

    }
    

    fun getContent(): Content? {
        return content
    }

    fun updateContent(newContent: Content) {
        val gson = Gson()
        val json = gson.toJson(newContent)
        
        val contentReference = database.getReference("content")
        contentReference.setValue(json)
    }
}
```

now I'm testing this class using Junit4
here:

```
class SdDataManagerTest {

    private lateinit var sdDataManager: SdDataManager

    @Before
    fun initialize() {
        sdDataManager = SdDataManager()
    }

    @Test
    fun updateContent() {
        sdDataManager.test()
    }
}
```

when I created addOnSuccessListener it didn't call

Answer (score 0):

If you created your database after downloading the `google-services.json` *and* you created it in a non-default/US region, you'll need to specify the URL for your data in code like this:

```
private var database: FirebaseDatabase = Firebase.database("URL of your database")
```

Comment: private var database: FirebaseDatabase = Firebase
        .database("https://poetry-and-prose-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/"), it also don't work